# Unable to get videos list on horizontal list

Tags: android, flutter, dart, youtube-api

currently I am fetching the videos from YouTube. The code below just lists out my videos vertically. I want the videos to be listed horizontally. I tried different approaches, but could not succeed. I tried a bunch of options, but was only left with a number of errors. So I am in need of help on what change should I implement.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
    }
    
    class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      Channel _channel;
      bool _isLoading = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initChannel();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]);
    
    
      }
    
    
    
    
      //UCtfK5Khr3psKzUP9HuYYgrw
      _initChannel() async {
        Channel channel = await APIService.instance
            .fetchChannel(channelId: 'Random#');
        setState(() {
          _channel = channel;
        });
      }
    
      _buildProfileInfo() {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          height: 100.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                offset: Offset(0, 1),
                blurRadius: 6.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(_channel.profilePictureUrl),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 12.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      _channel.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    // Text(
                    //   '${_channel.subscriberCount} subscribers',
                    //   style: TextStyle(
                    //     color: Colors.grey[600],
                    //     fontSize: 16.0,
                    //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    //   ),
                    //   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _buildVideo(Video video) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => VideoScreen(id: video.id),
            ),
          ),
          child:
       Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            height: 140.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  width: 150.0,
                  image: NetworkImage(video.thumbnailUrl),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    video.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _loadMoreVideos() async {
        _isLoading = true;
        List<Video> moreVideos = await APIService.instance
            .fetchVideosFromPlaylist(playlistId: _channel.uploadPlaylistId);
        List<Video> allVideos = _channel.videos..addAll(moreVideos);
        setState(() {
          _channel.videos = allVideos;
        });
        _isLoading = false;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 30,
              title: Text('Jiwdo Pani Audio Video'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[900],
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => Get.to(UserMenu()))),
    
    
    
          body: _channel != null
              ? NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
            onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollDetails) {
              if (!_isLoading &&
                  _channel.videos.length != int.parse(_channel.videoCount) &&
                  scrollDetails.metrics.pixels ==
                      scrollDetails.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
                _loadMoreVideos();
              }
              return false;
            },
    
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 1 + _channel.videos.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return _buildProfileInfo();
                }
                Video video = _channel.videos[index - 1];
                return _buildVideo(video);
              },
            ),
          )
          : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor, // Red
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listView builder into the container and try to add width and height.

```
Container( 
   width : 500,
   height : 500,
   child:ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 1 + _channel.videos.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              return _buildProfileInfo();
            }
            Video video = _channel.videos[index - 1];
            return _buildVideo(video);
          },
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#9b7a1 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'.                                                                                
          This is what I received as an error.

Comment: on which line you got this error ?